# Изменения текста тэга по нажатию кнопки html

Tags: html

У нас есть вот такой код, у тэга p есть атрибут title где хранится полная дата, вопрос, как можно сделать что бы при нажатии на кнопку ниже текст в тэге p заменялся текстом из атрибута title, и при повторном клике уже обратно на тот который был.

Пример:

10 дней. 1 час назад

Клик()

2021-01-24 16:37:06.050669

Клик()

10 дней. 1 час назад

```html
<p class="date" title="2021-01-24 16:37:06.050669">10 дней. 1 час назад</p>
<button type="button"></button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Быстрое решение на чистом JS

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('button.toggle_date');

for (const el of elements) {

el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const p = e.target.previousElementSibling;
    const title = p.title;
    const html = p.innerHTML;
    p.innerHTML = title;
    p.title = html;
  })
}
```

```html
<p class="date" title="2021-01-24 16:37:06.050669">10 дней. 1 час назад</p>
<button class="toggle_date" type="button"></button>
```

Будет работать только если кнопка идёт сразу за тегом `p`.
Если они будут в разных местах или на разных уровнях вложенности, то нужно переписывать код и давать уникальные идентификаторы тегу и кнопке, чтобы можно было выполнять поиск соответствующего `p`